# Prove the squared vector 2-norm is $\leq$ sum of 1-norm and infinity-norm

Tags: matrices, vectors, normed-spaces, infinity

How do I prove that 
$$\|x\|_2^2 \leq \|x\|_1  \|x\|_\infty?$$

Comment: Try writing out the left-hand side, then notice that $|x_i| \leq \|x\|_\infty$ for each $i$. So you can introduce an inequality and factor out $\|x\|_\infty$...

Comment: $$\int f^2 d\mu=\int |f|\,\,|f| d\mu \le \|f\|_\infty\,\int |f| d\mu =\|f\|_\infty\,\,\|f\|_1$$

Answer (score 3):

This is the Holder inequality with $p=1$ and $q=\infty$. In addition, we can prove this inequality using the following way:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \vert x_i\vert^2=\sum_{i=1}^n \vert x_i\vert \vert x_i\vert\leq \max_{i}\vert x_i\vert\sum_{i=1}^n \vert x_i\vert=\Arrowvert x \Arrowvert_1 \Arrowvert x\Arrowvert_\infty.$$